# ImageMagick convert

Tags: conversion, imagemagick

convert is not working on the Linux server I am using

```
$ convert exploss_stumps.jpg exploss_stumps.eps  
convert: missing an image filename `exploss_stumps.eps' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2838
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Verify that what you are trying to accomplish is valid.  You're trying to convert a raster image into a vector which is a non-trivial exercise and certainly beyond the scope of imagemagick:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#vector

> In other words, any output from IM will never be a true vector format. While it can convert its internal raster format into a vector format file, the result is only a superficial vector image wrapper around an image in raster format.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to need to specify more details.

- ImageMagick version
- is it a distribution package or compiled from source?
- Platform? (e.g. i386 on Core 2 Duo)
- Distribution? (e.g. Ubuntu i386 9.10 Karmic Koala)

Have you confirmed that the original image is valid? (Use ImageMagick's [`identify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) command)

Is Ghostscript (`gs`), and related fonts installed?

Use `-debug` to get more details.

```
convert -debug exploss_stumps.jpg exploss_stumps.eps
convert exploss_stumps.jpg exploss_stumps.png
```